# $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies\ \sum a_n^2$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum a_n$ with $a_n>0$ is convergent, then is $\sum {a_n}^2$ **always** convergent? Either prove it or give a counter example.

Im trying in this way, Suppose $a_n \in [0,1] \ \forall\  n.\ $ Then ${a_n}^2\leq a_n\ \forall\  n.$ Therefore by comparison test $\sum {a_n}^2$ converges.

So If $a_n$ has certain restrictions then the result is true.
 what about the general case?

How to proceed further?
Hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n\to0$.

Comment: @sranthrop It's a funny thing, we posted at the same time and it says EXACTLY the same!.

Comment: $\sum a_n$ convergent implies that $a_n\rightarrow 0$, then you always have $a_n\in [0,1]$ for $n$ large.

Comment: Are people still answering this question?

Comment: Your reasoning forgets the cases when $a_n$ is negative.  Then $a_n^2 > a_n$, even as $a_n$ approaches 0.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Hint:** Since, $a_i>0\forall i\ge 1$, $$\sum_{n=1}^N a_i^2\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\right)^2\ \forall N\ge 1$$

Comment: I like this argument best. It requires no new work. Since the original series converges, it's sum exists as a real number, so the square does also. The result follows naturally.

Answer (score 10):

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, hence from somewhere upward we have $0<a_n<1$, now use comparison test...

Answer (score 7):

Looks like there has been some significant editing but to answer the question as given, as I interpret it, does $\sum a_n$ convergent imply $\sum a_n^2$ convergent for $a_n$ not necessarily non-negative?

The answer is no. Take $a_{2n+1} = 1/\sqrt{n}$ and $a_{2n} = -1/\sqrt{n}$. Then the partial sums will be $s_{2n} = 0$ and $s_{2n+1} = 1/\sqrt{n}$. This means $s_n \to 0$ and the series converges.

However, $a_{2n}^2 = 1/n$ and $a_{2n+1}^2 = 1/n$, so $s_{2n} = 2 \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$ in this case. This is the harmonic series and it diverges.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

If $\sum a_n$ converges then $a_n\to 0$

Comment: Indeed, it is! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find some $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $0<a_n<1$ for every $n\ge n_0$.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the limit comparison test after you get $a_n\to 0$ by the n-th term test.