# Is it true that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{a_{n}} $ converge $ \Rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} $ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $ a_n $ be a non-negative sequence, such that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{a_{n}} $ converge. Is it true that  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} $ converge?

I think that it is. But I want to make sure because it appeared in my final exam. Here is my reasoning:

Since $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{a_{n}} $ converges, $ \sqrt{a_{n}}\underset{n\to\infty}{\to}0 $ and thus $ a_{n}\underset{n\to\infty}{\to}0 $. So there exists some $ n_0 $ such that, for all $ n>n_0$, it follows that $ 0\leq a_{n}<\frac{1}{2} $. Thus, for each $ n>n_0 $ we have

$$ a_{n}<\sqrt{a_{n}} .$$

So, from the comparison test, we get the convergence of

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}. $$

Do you agree?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: And a few more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493756/prove-that-if-suma-n-converges-absolutely-then-suma-n2-converges-abs?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282109/sum-a-n-converges-implies-sum-a-n2-converges?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is correct, this is just a slick, slightly hidden comparison test. Note, however, that the converse does not hold! For example, with $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\frac{\pi^2}{6}<\infty,$$
(this is the [Basel Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)) but
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{a_n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n},$$
which diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that proof is fine, as an alternative since

$$\sum a_n \le \left(\sum \sqrt{a_n}\right)^2$$

the series converges.

Comment: We do not know that $ a_n \neq 0 $

Comment: Yes, I didn’t see at first that condition. I’ve proposed an alternative but your one is simpler.